# Static Library; Unused Symbols; Definitions in Header

Tags: c++, static-libraries, code-size

I'm creating an HAL for an embedded system and part of that is re-creating `printf` functionality (via a class called `Printer`). Because it is an embedded system, code-space is critical and I would like to exclude floating-point support in `printf` by default, but allow the user of my HAL to include it on a project-by-project basis without having to recompile my library.

All of my classes have their method definitions inline in the header file.

[`printer.h`](https://github.com/DavidZemon/PropWare/blob/release-2.0-nightly/PropWare/printer.h) looks something like....

```cpp
class Printer {
    public:
        Printer (const PrintCapable *printCapable)
             : m_printCapable(printCapable) {}

        void put_char (const char c) { ... }

#ifdef ENABLE_PRINT_FLOAT
        void put_float (const float f) { ... }
#endif

        void printf (const char fmt[], ...) {
            // Stuffs...

#ifdef ENABLE_PRINT_FLOAT
            // Handle floating point support
#endif
        }

    private:
        const PrintCapable *m_printCapable;
}

// Make it very easy for the user of this library to print by defining an instance for them
extern Printer out;
```

Now, it is my understanding that this should work great.

[`printer.cpp`](https://github.com/DavidZemon/PropWare/blob/release-2.0-nightly/PropWare/printer.cpp) is nice and simple:

```cpp
#include <printer.h>
#include <uart/simplexuart.h>

const SimplexUART _g_simplexUart;
const Printer     out(&_g_simplexUart);
```

**Unnecessary code bloat:**
If I compile my library with and project without `ENABLE_PRINT_FLOAT` defined, then code size is 9,216 kB.

**Necessary code bloat:**
If I compile both library and project with `ENABLE_PRINT_FLOAT`, code size is 9,348 kB.

**Necessary code blo.... oh wait, it's not bloated:**
If I compile the project with and the library *without* `ENABLE_PRINT_FLOAT`, I would *expect* to see the same as above. But no... instead I have code size of 7,092 kB and a program that doesn't execute correctly.

**Minimum Size:**
If I compile both are compiled without `ENABLE_PRINT_FLOAT`, then the code size is only 6,960 kB.

How can I achieve my goal of small code size, flexible classes, and easy-to-use?

Build system is CMake. Full project source is [here](https://github.com/DavidZemon/PropWare/tree/release-2.0-nightly).

[Main file](https://github.com/DavidZemon/PropWare/blob/release-2.0-nightly/Examples/Hello/Hello_Demo.cpp) is nice and simple:

```cpp
#include <printer.h>

void main () {
    int i = 0;

    while (1) {
        out.printf("Hello world! %u %05.2f\n", i, i / 10.0);
        ++i;
        delay(250); // 1/4 second delay
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have different definition of `inline` functions in different translation units you have undefined behavior. Since your `printf()` definition changes with the setting of the `ENABLE_PRINT_FLOAT` macro you just see this effect.

Typically the compiler won't inline functions if it considers them too complicated. It would create out of line implementations and pick a random one when linking. Since the are all the same picking a random is OK ... oh wait, they are different and the program may be broken.

You *could* make floating point support a template parameter of your `printf()` function: the function would be called using

```
out.printf<false>("%d\n", i);
out.printf<true>("%f", f);
```

The implementation of `printf()` would delegate to suitable internal functions (to have the compiler merge definitions where they are identical) with the floating point support being disabled for the `false` case: it could do nothing, fail, or assert.

It may be simpler not do any conditional support in the first place and rather use a stream-like interface: since the formatting functions for the different types are separate, only those actually being used are picked up.

If it is an option for you library to use C++11 you could use variadic template to deal with the situation: the individual formatter would be implemented as separate functions which are dispatched to inside `printf()`: this way there is no `printf()` function which needs to handle all formatting. Instead, only the type formatters needed would be pulled in. The implementation could look something like this:

```
inline char const* format(char const* fmt, int value) {
    // find format specifier and format value accordingly
    // then adjust fmt to point right after the processed format specifier
    return fmt;
}
inline char const* format(char const* fmt, double value) {
    // like the other but different
}
// othe formatters

inline int printf(char const* fmt) { return 0; }
template <typename A, typename... T>
inline int printf(char const* fmt, A&& arg, T&& args) {
    fmt = format(fmt, std::forward<A>(arg));
    return 1 + printf(fmt, std::forward<T>(args));
)
```

Clearly, there are different approaches how common code between different formatter can be factored out. However, the overall idea should work. Ideally, the generic code would do as little work as possible to have the compiler merge all non-trivial code between the different uses. As a nice side-effect this implementation could make sure that the format specifiers are matching the objects being passed and either produce a suitable error or appropriately handle the format in some way.

Comment: So why is the definition of the method in the library when it's only in a header file and not the source?

Comment: If you compiled the source for the library and the compiler decided that it is too complicated to inline it may just create a copy. It may also create a version just to add debug symbols. Making functions `inline`, whether explicit or implicit, is just a promise to the compiler that it will be provided (with an identical definition) in all translation units where it is used. The compiler is free not to take advantage of this promise.

Comment: Lots of ideas you've put out there, thank you! So far, I don't see any that are ideal for my situation. Stream interface _would_ work great, but the community using the Parallax Propeller would never go for it. They are too C-centric and it's a challenge enough to get anyone to use C++ and classes.

Comment: C++11 is not available - we're stuck on GCC 4.6.

Comment: You'd really only need [variadic templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2242.pdf) and, maybe, [rvalue references](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2118.html). Both features are available starting with GCC 4.3 according to the [C++ status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html): just use the flag `-std=c++0x` to get the support available (rvalue references aren't really needed but variadic templates you'd need).

Comment: I just noticed the use of std::forward. Is that required? The std namespace is out of the question, as this chip only has 32kB of program space (hence forth the desperate measures to shrink code as much as possible). I'm reading a bunch on the variadic templates and trying to wrap my head around it all, but it certainly is a lot of new info.

Comment: Finally, I found a complete example of exactly this, without use of std namespace! http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack will try to implement it tomorrow evening and see if it works

Comment: Especially when only built-in types are involved you shouldn't need rvalue references or `std::forward<...>(...)`. That said, `std::forward<...>(..)` is straight forward to implement in a few lines and happens entirely at compile-time (it just makes its argument look different depending on how the original argument was passed). The key feature to make thing look cute are variadic templates.

Comment: Just wanted to come back here and thank you for all your help. I finally got PropWare compiling again with the template system as you suggested. It has brought on new code bloat that needs working out, but at least it's functional! Ran into lots more issues. If anyone else tries this and runs into issues, perhaps you can find the fix [here](http://forums.parallax.com/showthread.php/158375-Code-bloat-when-linking-against-full-PropWare-library).